# TCL issue - file path

Tags: tcl, xilinx

I'm having an issue with a TCL hook script.
There's a *.vhd file that I need to open using this line of code:

```
set f [open C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/myfile.vhd]
```

this file is set to be part of xil_defaultlib and I try to access it using the library, since the TCL script should be for others to use and they won't be able to access the file using the path I mentioned above.
I've tried choosing the work library instead and referencing the file the following way:

```
set f [open work.myfile.vhd]
```

but the TCL console writes:

```
couldn't open "work.myfile.vhd": no such file or directory
```

What would be the correct way to open the file using the work or xil_defaultlib libraries as the path to it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only guess that you are using Xilinx Vivado from the reference `xil_defaultlib`. You can try using `set f [open [get_files test.vhd]]`

Comment: @Rakend You need to be careful, as that command name indicates that it may return a list of several files. When filenames may have spaces in (more common on Windows than Linux) the difference can be important.

Comment: The set f [open [get_files test.vhd]] works but for some reason, when I use the TCL script as a pre-synthesis and then run a synthesis, the Vivado finishes the synthesis with an error saying : "[runtcl-1] couldn't open "": no such file or directory".
Any idea why it won't run the script in the synthesis but will run it as is using run tcl script option?